# Equivalent to vim's `:set paste`

Tags: evil

Sometimes when I use paste in emacs the indentation gets messed up.

In vim I would use `:set paste` before pasting. I'm in evil mode but it says: `State paste cannot be set as initial Evil state`.

Is there something else I can do?

Example pasting this:

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

```
http {
  include    conf/mime.types;
  include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  index    index.html index.htm index.php;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
```

Ends up like this:

```
http {                                                                          
  include    conf/mime.types;                                                   
    include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;                                           
      include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;                                       
        index    index.html index.htm index.php;                                

  default_type application/octet-stream;                                        
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '     
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
```

Comment: You'll have a better chance of an answer if you could explain what the vim command does.

Comment: It sets a Vim option that ensures no auto-indenting happens for pasted code.

Comment: What mode are you using?  I have evil, and I've tried pasting C (with c-basic-offset set to something different), javascript, and the stuff you have above in conf-mode and it's pasting exactly what I copy with no reindentation.

Comment: @JeffSpaulding Is there a way to check the mode with a command? I'm using evil but I'm not sure what mode the file automatically opens up in.

Comment: My bad, I meant the major mode you're having issues in, like c-mode.  In your modeline, it's the first thing in the parenthesis.  You can tell for sure with C-h m and looking for the first line that says "blah-mode defined in `blah.el'".

Comment: `M-: major-mode`

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986592/any-emacs-command-like-paste-mode-in-vim). Selected answer is what I personally do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, even with Evil Emacs ain't Vim.  Things like `:set option` won't work, simply because Evil concentrates on implementing text editing capabilities, not complete Vim emulation including Vim's options.  I strongly recommend to learn about Emacs settings, minor modes and whatever else you encounter on your way.  This includes habits like switching from using Vim in the terminal to using Emacs in graphical mode or keeping an Emacs instance open as opposed to keep opening and closing Vim instances.

The closest thing to `:set paste` would be `M-x electric-indent-mode` (and ensuring it has been disabled by checking the echo area) except it doesn't change anything about paste behavior in graphical or textual mode for me.  Please provide a minimal reproduction example starting from `make emacs` as described in Evil's [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#bug-reports) (unless it's not Evil-specific, then `emacs -Q` is sufficient as starting point).

Comment: I have an emacs daemon running that I can open and close in terminal but it always actually open. And yes learning emacs is what I'm doing, if it wasn't I wouldn't be here I'd be back on vim.

Comment: I'm trying `M-x electric-indent-mode` but it is the same. I feel like this would be a common question for anyone using terminal. I'll update my answer with the info later if no one replies.

Comment: Does it work as expected in the GUI? If yes, you've found a compelling reason to switch.